# HTML5 video doesn't Auto-play on Android 4.4 (Nexus 5) for PhoneGap Application

Tags: html, video, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat, autoplay

My app was working with previous Android versions.But now with Android 4.4 it's not.

Understand that Android 4.4 (Nexus 5) coming with built in Chrome. I know that;  Chrome on Android disabled (not allowed) Auto-play HTML5 videos.

Is there any way to play HTML5 videos automatically in Phonegap Applications? Any plugins etc?
I need to play video if user don't touch screen some time.

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this one out? I'm stuck with the same problem, although I've been using jaeger25's Html5Video-plugin on previous versions... I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible (through chromium Webview) anymore... :/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to `false` just like with native apps as [described here](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/78586868260/getting-the-html5-video-tag-to-work-in-cordova-for).

Comment: is there any option in config to add. I got for ios but not for android.